# listBox wpf c# sql вывод информации конкретного элемента по клику

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, mvvm

у меня есть listBox хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку,которая содержится в каждом элементе выводилась инфомрация по конкретному элементу,вся инфа в бд хранится,в заголовках элемента находится поле NameOfAdvert и DateOfPublished также в бд есть поле Content где находится информация по элементу,мне необходимо как-то выводить эту  инфу по клику,допустим,в MessageBox.Show(advert.Content); если честно,когда я дошел до этого,я понял,что ничего не могу придумать,прошу помочь решить эту проблему
**View**:

```
WpfApp1:ContextHolder>
        <WpfApp1:ContextHolder.Commands>
            <WpfApp1:CommandBinding RoutedCommand="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Delete}"
                                  RelayCommand="{Binding RemoveCommand}"/>
            <WpfApp1:CommandBinding RoutedCommand="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Open}"
                                  RelayCommand="{Binding ShowContentCommand}"/>
        </WpfApp1:ContextHolder.Commands>
        <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxName"  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectetListBoxIndex}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectetListBoxItem}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding ItemForListBox}" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" Margin="81,42,0,0" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="238">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=NameOfAdvert}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=DateOfPublished}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <Button Width="150" Height="30" Content="Удалить"
                            Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Delete}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <Button Width="150" Height="30" Content="Читать"
                            Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Open}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </WpfApp1:ContextHolder>
**ViewModel**:
```

```
public class UserMainWindowVm
   {
       Advert advert = new Advert();
       public ObservableCollection<Advert> ItemForListBox { get; set; }
       UserContext db;
       public Advert SelectetListBoxItem { get; set; }
       public Advert SelectetListBoxIndex { get; set; }

       private RelayCommand _removeCommand;
       private RelayCommand _showContent;

       public UserMainWindowVm()
       {
           
           ItemForListBox = new ObservableCollection<Advert>();
           db = new UserContext();
           db.AdvertsSet.Load();
           ItemForListBox = db.AdvertsSet.Local;
           
       }

       public RelayCommand RemoveCommand => _removeCommand ?? (_removeCommand = new RelayCommand(RemoveMetod));
       public RelayCommand ShowContentCommand => _showContent ?? (_showContent = new RelayCommand(ShowContentMetod));

      

       private void RemoveMetod(object parameter)
       {
           if (parameter is Advert item)
           {
               Advert adv = SelectetListBoxItem;
               db.AdvertsSet.Remove(item);
           }
               
       }

       private void ShowContentMetod(object parameter)
       {
         // 
           MessageBox.Show();

       }

       
   }
```

```
UserContext
```

```
class UserContext:DbContext
    {
        public UserContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Advert> AdvertsSet { get; set; }
    }
```

Прошу подсказку как реализовать

Comment: А в чем проблема? Делаете кнопку, привязываете ее через `FindAncestor`, чтоб была привязка к основной VM (уровень выше) к `ICommand`, да и все, делаете что надо по событию. Из замечаний по вашему коду: `ItemForListBox` - забудьте про интерфейс, как бы вы это назвали, если бы была библиотека? `db = new UserContext();` - база и вся работа с объектами базы (удаление, поиск, добавление), это Model слой, сделайте отдельный класс, который будет работать чисто с базой, ибо `UserMainWindowVm` ну не как не должен за это отвечать. `MessageBox` - это View, а значит вызываеть его в VM нарушение MVVM.

Comment: Если честно совсем не понял про FindAncestor,никогда его раньше не использовал,у меня уже забинджена кнопка на событие,я лишь хочу спросить как решить мою задачу,а именно выводить `Content` селектченого объекта
И если MessageBox нельзя вызывать в VM,то тогда где его использовать?

Comment: `совсем не понял про FindAncestor` - когда вы пишете `{Binding SomePropert}`, то самое `SomePropert` WPF пытается найти в `DataContext` объекта. Когда вы пишете `<ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding SomeCollection}">`, то **все** объекты этой коллекции имеют `DataContext = (Объект внутри коллекции SomeCollection)`, то есть в вашем случае, это `Advert`. Теперь задайте себе вопрос, есть ли там нужная команда, к которой вы имеете доступ, контролируете ее, у который есть Action? Я у вас такого не вижу.

Comment: `FindAncestor` - это некий тип привязки, который указывает "Ей, найти мне на уровне выше нужное свойство". То есть, мы пишем `{Binding SomeProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=SomeItem}}` и привязка начнет идти по дереву вверх, пытаясь найти первый `SomeItem`, у которого возьмет свойство `SomeProperty`, то есть так можно привязать команду, которая находится рядом с коллекцией, а не внутри объекта. Вот вам и надо сделать такую команду и привязать ее, а параметром просто передавать `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`.